# SQL Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LI'

Tags: sql

I have written the following query but it is giving me following error. Can you please tell me where is the problem in the query.

> **Error** :
>   SQL Error: An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a
>   context where a condition is expected, near 'LI'.

**Query** :

```
SELECT Orders.Day,
       Orders.Month,
       Orders.Year,
       Orders.Orders_Count,
       Orders.PaymentAmount,
       Orders.Total_Payment_Authorized,
       Orders.Total_Payment_Received,
       Orders.SalesTax1,
       Orders.SalesTax2,
       Orders.SalesTax3,
       Orders.TotalShippingCost,
       Orders.OrderDetails_Count,
       Orders.Quantity,
       Orders.COGS,
       Orders.Profit,
       Orders.ProfitMargin
FROM   (SELECT Orders.Day,
               Orders.Month,
               Orders.Year,
               Orders.Orders_Count,
               Orders.PaymentAmount,
               Orders.Total_Payment_Authorized,
               Orders.Total_Payment_Received,
               Orders.SalesTax1,
               Orders.SalesTax2,
               Orders.SalesTax3,
               Orders.TotalShippingCost,
               OrderDetails.OrderDetails_Count,
               OrderDetails.Quantity,
               OrderDetails.COGS,
               OrderDetails.Profit,
               OrderDetails.ProfitMargin
        FROM   (SELECT Datepart(DD, Orders.OrderDate)       AS Day,
                       Datepart(MM, Orders.OrderDate)       AS Month,
                       Datepart(YY, Orders.OrderDate)       AS Year,
                       Max(Orders.OrderDate)                AS OrderDate,
                       Max(Orders.ShipDate)                 AS ShipDate,
                       Count(Orders.OrderID)                AS Orders_Count,
                       Sum(Orders.PaymentAmount)            AS PaymentAmount,
                       Sum(Orders.Total_Payment_Authorized) AS Total_Payment_Authorized,
                       Sum(Orders.Total_Payment_Received)   AS Total_Payment_Received,
                       Sum(Orders.SalesTax1)                AS SalesTax1,
                       Sum(Orders.SalesTax2)                AS SalesTax2,
                       Sum(Orders.SalesTax3)                AS SalesTax3,
                       Sum(Orders.TotalShippingCost)        AS TotalShippingCost
                FROM   (((Orders WITH(NOLOCK)
                          LEFT JOIN PaymentMethods WITH(NOLOCK)
                            ON Orders.PaymentMethodID = PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodID)
                         LEFT JOIN ShippingMethods WITH(NOLOCK)
                           ON Orders.ShippingMethodID = ShippingMethods.ShippingMethodID)
                        LEFT JOIN Customers WITH(NOLOCK)
                          ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
                WHERE  Orders.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
                GROUP  BY Datepart(DD, Orders.OrderDate),
                          Datepart(MM, Orders.OrderDate),
                          Datepart(YY, Orders.OrderDate)) Orders
               INNER JOIN (SELECT Datepart(DD, Orders.OrderDate)                         AS Day,
                                  Datepart(MM, Orders.OrderDate)                         AS Month,
                                  Datepart(YY, Orders.OrderDate)                         AS Year,
                                  Count(OrderDetails.OrderDetailID)                      AS OrderDetails_Count,
                                  Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity)                             AS Quantity,
                                  Sum(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS COGS,
                                  CASE
                                    WHEN Sum(Vendor_Price) IS NULL THEN NULL
                                    ELSE Sum(( CASE
                                                 WHEN OrderDetails.ProductCode LIKE 'DSC-%' THEN OrderDetails.ProductPrice - Isnull(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price, 0)
                                                 ELSE OrderDetails.ProductPrice - OrderDetails.Vendor_Price
                                               END ) * OrderDetails.Quantity)
                                  END                                                    AS Profit,
                                  CASE Sum(OrderDetails.ProductPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity)
                                    WHEN 0 THEN 0
                                    ELSE Round(( ( Sum(OrderDetails.ProductPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) - Sum(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price * OrderDetails.Quantity) ) / Sum(OrderDetails.ProductPrice * OrderDetails.Quantity) ) * 100, 1)
                                  END                                                    AS ProfitMargin
                           FROM   (((Orders WITH(NOLOCK)
                                     LEFT JOIN PaymentMethods WITH(NOLOCK)
                                       ON Orders.PaymentMethodID = PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodID)
                                    LEFT JOIN ShippingMethods WITH(NOLOCK)
                                      ON Orders.ShippingMethodID = ShippingMethods.ShippingMethodID)
                                   LEFT JOIN Customers WITH(NOLOCK)
                                     ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
                                  LEFT JOIN OrderDetails WITH(NOLOCK)
                                    ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
                           WHERE  Orders.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96704'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96710'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96718'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96719'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96720'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96721'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96725'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96726'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96727'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96728'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96737'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96738'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96739'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96740'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96743'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96745'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96749'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96750'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96755'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96760'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96764'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96771'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96772'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96773'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96774'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96776'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96777'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96778'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96780'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96781'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96783'
                                  AND Orders.ShipPostalCode LIKE '96785'
                           GROUP  BY Datepart(DD, Orders.OrderDate),
                                     Datepart(MM, Orders.OrderDate),
                                     Datepart(YY, Orders.OrderDate)) OrderDetails
                 ON Orders.Day = OrderDetails.Day
                    AND Orders.Month = OrderDetails.Month
                    AND Orders.Year = OrderDetails.Year) Orders
ORDER  BY Orders.Day DESC,
          Orders.Month DESC,
          Orders.Year DESC
```

Comment: You're not using any wildcards in your `ShipPostalCode LIKE.....` criteria - you could simplify that to be a single criteria like this `AND Orders.ShipPostalCode IN ('96718', '96719', .....)` - just list all possible postal codes in the `IN (....)` part.

Comment: Can you pinpoint **where** in this rather convoluted and hard-to-read query that error occurs? Does double-clicking on the error message take you to the location of the error? If so: **where** is that??

Comment: How are you executing this query? Seems like it is getting truncated at one of the `LIKE` statements.

Comment: Agreed with @marc_s, you probably want to be using `in`. However, that would not be a direct transliteration of your query. `in` implies a logical OR operation, whereas you're using a logical AND. As it's impossible for a value to be, concurrently, more than one value your query will currently return 0 results.

Comment: So there is no way instaed of using IN ?

Comment: @user818671, of course, use `or`, correctly. So, ensure that you use parenthesis to separate out your `and` statements and your `or` statements. There is no difference between this and an `in` though.

Comment: `Orders` is aliased many times change it by adding an `i`  after that for inner select like `Ordersi`, `Ordersii` and so on. I think your aliases make error and if not those may return wrong results.